# Firebase upload image

Tags: swift, swift3, firebase-storage

I'm trying to upload an image to Firebase storage using following code:

```
let storageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference()
let imageRef = storageRef.child("AAA").child("BBB").child("CCC.jpeg")
let metaData = FIRStorageMetadata()
metaData.contentType = "image/jpeg"
if let uploadData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(sampleImage, 0.5){
            imageRef.put(uploadData, metadata: metaData, completion: { (metaData, error) in
                print("finished")
                if error != nil{
                    print(error!.localizedDescription)
                }else{
                    print("success")
                }
            })
        }else{
            print("Cannot convert image to JPEG format")
        }
```

The problem is that The above code doesn't do anything, in other words, nothing prints out. I have tried uploading strings to Firebase database, and it succeed. I've also checked the rules of Firebase storage:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

So, what did i do wrong? Is there anything that I need to set up? Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer*: Let's just say my middle name isn't SwiftLint.

Try this, and make sure your database rules are similar as well. You should get a link in your database that will point you to the image in storage.

```
if let theData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(sampleImage, 0.5) {
    self.helper(photoData:theData)
}
// ^^ this can happen elsewhere ^^

func upload(photoData:Data) {
    let imgName = Int(round(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)

    let metadata = FIRStorageMetadata()
    metadata.contentType = "image/jpeg"

    let imageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference().child("AAA/BBB/\(imgName).jpg")

    imageRef.put(photoData, metadata: metadata) { (metadata, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error uploading: \(error)")
            return
        }

        let data:[String:Any] = [
            "timeStamp":"\(Date())",
            "image":metadata!.downloadURL()!.absoluteString
        ]

        let dbRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
        dbRef.child("imageUploads").childByAutoId().setValue(data)

    }    
}
```

Comment: It still doesn't work even thought didn't try the following part: let data:[String:Any] = [
            "timeStamp":"\(Date())",
            "image":metadata!.downloadURL()!.absoluteString
        ]

        let dbRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
        dbRef.child("imageUploads").childByAutoId().setValue(data) But I did check the storage, and nothing is in there.

Answer (score 0):

Well, both of my original solution and @MGTLA solution are correct, the problem turns out to be the while loop after uploading image...which is unrelated to this topic.